# Html Regex remove year and format in title

Tags: html, regex

I have one title:

```
[b]Author Name - Book Title (2004) (PDF)[/b]
```

I want to remove (2004) and (PDF) in this title, I can separate Author Name and Book Title using this regex:

```
\[b\](.+?) - (.+?)\[/b\]
```

However, I don't know how to remove the year and its format.

I really appreciate any helps.

Comment: You should remove the HTML tag since that isn't actually relevant to the question.

Comment: Substitute pattern [`\(.*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/MEfAv3/1) with `''` in your language. (In Php it would be [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regex, it helps to be as specific as you can

```
\[b\](\w+(?: \w+)*) - (\w+(?: \w+)*) \(\d+\) \(\w+\)\[\/b\]
```

- `(\w+(?: \w+)*)`: Match series of words separated by spaces (numbers count as words)

  - `(?:)` is a non-capture group
- `\(\d+\) \(\w+\)`: Match (<numbers>) (<word>)

This will be much more efficient, and will not match malformed data rather than give you some undefined result. Adjust as you find invalid cases you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex [`/ \(.*?\)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/QMLlgW/1)

This matches everything that has a space preceding an open and close bracket.

I don't know which language you are using to run the regex on, so until you update your tags I can't put this into a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything like "HTML regex" except that it is possible to use a regex as a validation rule in HTML5 `<input>` tag.

The `[b]Author Name - Book Title (2004) (PDF)[/b]` does not correspond to HTML at all.

If you are sure that

- Author(s) do not contain a hyphen (strong assumption)
- Year and format are always present as shown

you can filter out the two fields the same way you select the author and title...

You did not specify the flavor of regex/engine, but with the syntax you used, something like the following should work:

```
\[b\](.+?) - (.+?) \(\d{4}\) \(.*?\)\[/b\]
```

A Perl RE could look like

```
/\[b\] \s* (.+?) \s+ - \s+ (.+?) \s+ \(\d{4}\) \s+ \(.*?\) \s* \[\/b\]/x
```

returning the author and title in $1 and $2, respectively. If necessary, using parentheses you can capture the 2 attributes, too.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this way